# Discharge Characteristics of Lithium Ion Battery

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, discharge

I am doing a simple experiment to analyse the discharge characteristics of a Lithium Ion battery to see how long it takes to discharge.

I have a 12V 4000mAh battery. Once charged, using a voltmeter I find that it has about 12V across it. I then put it in a simple circuit with a 6 ohm resistor. I estimated that this is the resistance that would cause it to discharge in 2 hours. After 10 minutes the voltage has dropped to 5V. This seems wrong and I may be doing this incorrectly.

Can anyone suggest a better way to measure the discharge characteristics of this battery.

Comment: Discharging a Li-Ion battery like that can damage it, a 12 V battery probably has 3 sets of cells in series. You should not discharge Li-Ion cells below 3 V per cell so the discharging should stop at 9 V. Properly measuring the capacity of such cells requires special equipment.

Comment: I would also like to add that the voltage should probably be closer to 13V (maybe 4.2V per cell, 3 cells, makes 12.6V). How are you charging the battery? Maybe it isn't fully charged like you think it is?

Comment: Thanks. I had suspected exactly that. What sort of "special equipment" would be required. Would it be within the budget of an amateur ?

Comment: @joshJobin I don't think it is fully charged. Even after 48 hours the light on the charging plug is still red. I think the battery is damaged. I may buy another but I would like to avoid damaging the battery next time.

Comment: A 3 cell lipo/li-ion would be almost fully charged at 12 V. If the battery completely discharged in 10 minutes of 2 A it sounds like your 4 Ah is really a 120 mAh battery. If you bought 3 "4 Ah" *something*Fire cells on ebay or similar "good value" products this is to be expected.

Comment: This is the battery in question http://www.amazon.co.uk/4800mAh-Rechargeable-Portable-Lithium-ion-Battery/dp/B014SRBH0C/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1456399762&sr=8-10&keywords=lithium+ion+battery

Comment: It's a 3 cell lithium polymer pack. At that price I would expect 2 Ah or less from a 3 cell battery, so the capacity claim of 4.8 Ah is almost certainly bogus. Considering that it has no external balance plugs, it is likely that it has a low voltage cutoff and balancing circuitry built in.

Comment: You should have mentioned it is a LiPo pack instead of Li Ion ! Maybe this device: http://www.ebay.nl/itm/iMAX-B6AC-Digital-RC-Lipo-NiMH-Battery-Balance-Charger-Discharger-/231844284263?hash=item35faff0767:g:HGQAAOSwG-1Wvt8D is what you need.

Comment: @FakeMoustache The seller lists it as "Li-Ion" and the pack itself states "super polymer lithium-ion battery" so it's understandable that OP got confused.

Answer (score -2):

2A isn't a trivial draw rate!

It's very possible that your battery pack's internal resistance is many times that. If your battery pack was getting noticably hot, then you probably spent more power heating up your batts than heating up the external "test" resistor.

Try with a 24ohm resistor & a voltage meter. When the meter registers 9v, turn it off & call that "discharged" if it lasts longer than an hour, then you were definitely wasting most of your power against the batteries' internal resistances.

Comment: I voted down your answer because it is most unlikely that lithium battery would have even 1 Ohm of resistance, let alone more than 6 Ohms. Also, you compared draw rate directly to internal resistance, which is sloppy thinking or writing. Finally, if the battery really is 4Ah, as stated, 2A is a high but not unreasonable draw rate.

Comment: @mkeith your opinion is your own, but you may want to check up on the various different lithium battery chemistries. considering the price of that battery pack and the mfgr specified 4800mAh rating, it's far more likely to be one of the higher-storage, but terrible discharge-rate chemistries with very high internal resistance.